# Example pipeline for TFRecords with chunking for long input sequences

Tags: tensorflow, time-series, file-format

I'm trying to optimise the input pipeline for a model I am using that uses GRUs. The data consists of a large number of files that contain time series of length 5000 with dimensionality of 50. I know that it isn't feasible to feed a single sequence of length 5000 into an RNN owing to the vanishing gradient, and you should instead try to chunk it into (5000-seq_len) overlapping chunks, where seq_len is a more manageable length, say 200 timesteps.

The most obvious method for getting this to work with TFRecords/SequenceExamples is to simply have each chunk included as a new SequenceExample within the same file. This seems massively inefficient however, as the majority of data in the resulting TFRecords file will be duplicate data.

Is there a better method of doing this? I've seen very few examples of how to use TFRecords that don't involve images, and no examples that use non-trivial sequence lengths!

For example:

```
def chunk_save_tfrecords(X, file_path_prefix, seq_length):

    # Generate tfrecord writer
    result_tf_file = file_path_prefix + '.tfrecords' 
    with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(result_tf_file) as writer:

        # Chunk the data
        for i in range(int(X.shape[0] - seq_length)):
            chunk = X[i:i+seq_length]

            data_features = [
                tf.train.Feature(
                    float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=chunk[t])) 
                                for t in range(seq_length)] # FloatList per timestep
            feature_lists = tf.train.FeatureLists(
                feature_list={
                    'data': tf.train.FeatureList(feature=data_features)})

            serialized = tf.train.SequenceExample(
                feature_lists=feature_lists).SerializeToString()
            writer.write(serialized)

def save_tfrecords(X, file_path_prefix):

    # Generate tfrecord writer
    result_tf_file = file_path_prefix + '.tfrecords' 
    with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(result_tf_file) as writer:

        data_features = [
            tf.train.Feature(
                float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=X[t])) 
                            for t in range(X.shape[0])] # FloatList per timestep
        feature_lists = tf.train.FeatureLists(
            feature_list={
                'data': tf.train.FeatureList(feature=data_features)})

        serialized = tf.train.SequenceExample(
            feature_lists=feature_lists).SerializeToString()
        writer.write(serialized)

test = np.random.randn(5000,50)
save_tfrecords(test, 'test')
chunk_save_tfrecords(test, 'test_chunk', 200)
```

save_tfrecords creates a 1MB file, while chunk_save_tfrecords creates a 200MB file!

Comment: My recommendation would be to do this transformation on-the-fly as part your model's input pipeline. You then never need materialize the data to disk. Take a look at the newer `Dataset` API: https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets , which is designed to make it easy to write flexible input pipelines.

Comment: Thanks for posting this question. I've been working on something similar. One question I have is: how important is it that the chunks overlap? That seems like a lot of redundancy. Would it be a bad thing to create chunks that don't overlap (e.g.  `i` increments by `seq_length` instead of by 1)? Of course then you'd have to decide what to do with the partial chunk at the end. But in that case you could, say, allow the final chunk to overlap with the second-to-last chunk like so: `final_chunk = X[x_len-seq_length:x_len]` where `x_len = X.shape[0]`.